# How to get roles of user from wso2 IS into the third party application configured as service provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, grafana, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Configured grafana with wso2 IS for authentication, Authentication is working fine but I am not able get user role into grafana from WSO2 IS. Can anyone guide on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the roles(groups) claim in the SP you registered for grafana. You can following the steps in [doc](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/configuring-claims-for-a-service-provider/#claim-mapping) to add roles claims to the SP

If you are using new console, follow these steps

1. Go to the registered SP edit page
2. Select the user attributes tap
3. Add the role(groups) attributes
   [image]

In the access token, you can see the roles. (note: to always receive the roles in the access token make the roles attribute mandatory in the claims/attribute setting)